# PHP yii 2, is there a way to prefetch a related model with a condition

Tags: php, yii2

```
PriceAlert::find()->andWhere(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id])->orderBy('complete DESC, updated_at DESC')->with('product')
```

So i have recently discovered the "with" feature for Yii queries, as you can see in the query above, i'm fetching my price alerts with their related products, which saves me from having to loop through each price alert and fetching each product individually, but my question is there a way to force a condition on this, what i want is to get the price alerts with a condition on the products, so i only want to get the price alerts where a condition on their related products is true.

Comment: Looking for [this?](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#joining-with-relations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previous answer is incomplete, if you want to add a condition on products in the main query (not the one who will fetch the related records), you should simply use `joinWith()` instead of `with()`, e.g. :

```
PriceAlert::find()
    ->joinWith('product')
    ->andWhere(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id])
    ->andWhere(['>', 'product.price', 100])
    ->orderBy('complete DESC, updated_at DESC')
    ->all();
```

Or if you want to specify some extra conditions in the `ON` part of the JOIN query :

```
PriceAlert::find()
    ->joinWith(['product' => function ($q) {
        // add conditions here
    }])
    ->andWhere(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id])
    ->orderBy('complete DESC, updated_at DESC')
    ->all();
```

Read more about [Joining with Relations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#joining-with-relations).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in `with` method and closure.

```
...->with(['product' => function ($query) {
    $query->andWhere(/* product conditions here */);
}]);
```

See [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#with()-detail).

Comment: Please left some questions for me. :) beaten by 10 seconds.